# Google Chromeはchromeタグかgoogle-chromeタグのどちらが良いか？

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在Google Chromeに対し、二つのタグがあります。
chromeタグ(Google社のwebブラウザという説明があります)とgoogle-chromeタグの二つがあり、これは重複となると考えています。

自分の意見では、chromeは一般名詞かつGoogle Chromeの省略形なため好ましくなく、タグシノニムなどによってgoogle-chromeにフォワードするのが良いのではないかと考えています。

皆さんの意見はどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

google-chromeにフォワードで良いと思います。

Comment: ええと、こういう時はどうすれば良いのでしょう。更に質問でタグシノニムの提案を行なって、モデレーターの方にタグシノニムの投票をお願いすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: シノニムの提案を行いました。投票って出来ますか？http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome/synonyms

Comment: 残念ながら、信用度が1250点以上の人間(現在ユーザーを見る限り存在しないように見えます)&タグの解答スコアが5点以上の人しか出来ないため、私には不可能です。このような場合は他のモデレーターの方に協力を求めるしか無いのでしょうか？

Comment: モデレータとしてシノニムを承認できたので、承認しました。